# Using a lookup to set the To: address on a sharepoint designer 2010 workflow email action

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, designer-workflow

I have a sharepoint designer 2010 workflow with a email action.  I want to set the value for the To: address to a field of the Current Item using a lookup ( [%Current Item:Vendor Contact%].  Unfortunately, i can't seem to figure out how to do this.....when i try to add the lookup with the cursor in the To: field....the lookup gets put automatically in the body of the email message.  Any idea what i'm doing wrong/how to do this?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the To: button, it should present you with an option to lookup the data. The other option is storing it in a dynamic string and using that, but the process is still the same, you need to click thr To button, not the Lookup button by the body.

Comment: Just saw what you are talking about.  Click the little book button..and then select "Workflow Lookup for a User".  Hate it when i miss the obvious.  Many thanks